# The correct HTTP method for resetting data

Tags: rest, http-method

I want to "reset" certain data in my database tables using a RESTful method but I'm not sure which one I should be using. `UPDATE` because I'm deleting records and updating the record where the ID is referenced (but never removing the record where ID lives itself), or `DELETE` because my main action is to delete associated records and updating is tracking those changes?

I suppose this action can be ran multiple times but the result will be the same, however the ID will always be found when "resetting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the DELETE method